# Как считать массив чисел с бинарного файла с помощью метода read()?

Tags: c++

```
void read(int* arr) {
    ifstream file_if;
    file_if.open("arr.txt", ios::binary);
    if (!file_if.is_open())
        cout << "error opening file for reading" << endl;
    else
        file_if.read((char*)&arr, size); 
    file_if.close();
}
```

> size - замер массива;

> file_if.read((char*)&arr, size); - чтение из файла сразу в целый массив, до этого была запись в файл "file_of.write((char*)&arr, size);"

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что вы хотите сказать строкой `file_if.read((char*)&arr, sizeof(arr));`. Насчет чтения бинарного файла я нашел хороший пример [тут](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/), надеюсь вам поможет

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` - это не размер массива, а размер указателя. 4 или 8 байт, в зависимости от архитектуры.

Comment: `file_if.read((char*)&arr, size);` фактически вы просто считали из файла указатель. Считали верно, передав именно адрес переменной-указателя `arr`, если, конечно, `size` равно `sizeof(arr)`. Другое дело, что вы 1. явно хотели иное, 2. смысла в чтении/записи указателя — никакого... Да, запись вы делали точно так же — указателя из переменной `arr`. Поскольку правильный вопрос вы не задали, дать ответ на не заданный вопрос не представляется возможным...

Comment: Наверное, вы имели в виду чтение в массив `arr[]`, который передается как аргумент. Тогда -- `file_if.read((char*)arr, size);` (1. т.е. читаете не по адресу параметра (это указатель на начало масива), а по адресу в этом указателе. 2. если size в байтах, если же это размер в элементах массива, то умножте на sizeof(int) (или просто на 4))

Comment: `(char*)&arr` -> `(char*)arr`, и, возможно, `size` -> `size * sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_if.read((char*)arr, size * sizeof(int));` - чтение целого массива;

`file_if.read((char*)&arr, sizeof(int));` - чтение одной переменной, той на которой стоит указатель `seekg()`(по умолчанию в начале файла);

`for (int index = 0; index < size; ++index) {file_if.read((char*)arr[index], sizeof(int));}`- чтение одного элемента в ваш массив под номером `index`;
Работает это так: считываем элемент с файла и сохраняем его в массив под номером `index`, после чего указатель перемещается на sizeof(int);